# wrong srcset attributes from httrack

Tags: bash, sed, httrack

I have spidered a website with *httracks* and a lot of files on different levels are generated. But the website uses `picture` / `source` tags with `srcset` attributes which *httrack* does not handle, all those pictures does not work well offline.

*httrack* can see the links if a use the option `Attempt to detect all links (even in unknown tags/javascript code)` (in winhttrack) and copied all images to the local storage. But it did not change the path to relative.

Now I need a script (powershell/gnu bash) which can edit all the html files to adapt the pathes in the `srcset`s to the correct relative path.

my idea would be a recursion for each folder with an additional `../` as parameter to insert/ replace with `sed`.

## what to do:

**example files:**

```
index.html
cat1/product1.html
cat2/option3/product5.html
```

each contains some picture tags like:

```
<picture>
     <source srcset="/images/img1_low.jpg, /images/img1_low_ret.jpg x2" media="(max-width: 470px)">
     <source srcset="/images/img1_med.jpg, /images/img1_med_ret.jpg x2" media="(max-width: 960px)">
     <source srcset="/images/img1_hi.jpg, /images/img1_hi_ret.jpg x2" media="(min-width: 961px)">
     <img src="../images/img1_hi.jpg" />
</picture>
```

inside the image tag the path is always correct done from `httrack`: (`images/img1_hi.jpg`, `../images/img1_hi.jpg`, `../../images/img1_hi.jpg`)

*but the source tag also must contain the matching pathes:*

in index.html:

```
<picture>
     <source srcset="images/img1_low.jpg, images/img1_low_ret.jpg x2" media="(max-width: 470px)">
     <source srcset="images/img1_med.jpg, images/img1_med_ret.jpg x2" media="(max-width: 960px)">
     <source srcset="images/img1_hi.jpg, images/img1_hi_ret.jpg x2" media="(min-width: 961px)">
     <img src="images/img1_hi.jpg" />
</picture>
```

in cat1/product1.html:

```
<picture>
     <source srcset="../images/img1_low.jpg, ../images/img1_low_ret.jpg x2" media="(max-width: 470px)">
     <source srcset="../images/img1_med.jpg, ../images/img1_med_ret.jpg x2" media="(max-width: 960px)">
     <source srcset="../images/img1_hi.jpg, ../images/img1_hi_ret.jpg x2" media="(min-width: 961px)">
     <img src="../images/img1_hi.jpg" />
</picture>
```

in cat2/option3/product5.html:

```
<picture>
     <source srcset="../../images/img1_low.jpg, ../../images/img1_low_ret.jpg x2" media="(max-width: 470px)">
     <source srcset="../../images/img1_med.jpg, ../../images/img1_med_ret.jpg x2" media="(max-width: 960px)">
     <source srcset="../images/img1_hi.jpg, ../../images/img1_hi_ret.jpg x2" media="(min-width: 961px)">
     <img src="../../images/img1_hi.jpg" />
</picture>
```

my attempt:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

function workfolder {
    # $1 = current folder
    # $2 = prefix upfolders

    pushd $PWD
    cd $1

    for i in $( ls ) ; do
        if [ -d $i ] ; then
            workfolder $i ../$2
        fi
    done

    for i in $( ls *.html ) ; do
        sed -i 's/srcset="images/srcset="$2images/g' $i
        sed -i 's/, images/, $2images/g' $i
    done

    popd

}

workfolder .
```

aside of too much errors the `$2` in the sed replacement is not solved but replaced litteraly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
function workfolder {
    # $1 = current folder
    # $2 = prefix upfolders

    pushd $PWD > /dev/null
    cd $1
    echo "=====^ $PWD ====="
    for i in $( ls ) ; do
        if [ -d $i ] ; then
            workfolder $i ..\\/$2
        fi
    done
    for i in $( ls *.html ) ; do
        echo " working on: $PWD/$i with $2"
        sed -i 's/srcset="image/srcset="'$2'image/g' $i
        sed -i 's/\,\ image/\,\ '$2'image/g' $i
    done
    popd > /dev/null
    echo "=====v $PWD ====="
}

workfolder .
```

traps are: using `$2` in the sed command at all (1st attempt was not expanded) and the correct escaping of `../` as 2nd parameter in a form usable in the sed commands

Comment: Nice! Or... if you want to just remove the `srcset` attribute completly: `sed --in-place 's/srcset="[^"]*"//g' $i`

Answer (score 1):

#### Summary

This method works within HTTrack and modifies files on-the-fly. It doesn't require a post-action script as described in the context of this question.

#### Solution

The issue `srcset` has in HTTrack is that, in browsers that support `srcset`, the images are not rendered. As the OP states; this occurs because the browser is trying to load the URL that HTTrack did not convert.

The solution (credit to [@jonathandavidarndt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2657515/jonathandavidarndt)) was to remove the `srcset` attribute completely, this would make modern browsers fallback to the `src` attribute and allow the image to display as intended.

To achieve this I leveraged [the `-V` option in HTTrack](https://manpages.debian.org/testing/httrack/httrack.1.en.html#V)

> -V : execute system command after each files ($0 is the filename: -V "rm $0") (--userdef-cmd )

The option value uses [the UNIX command `sed`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/sed) to transform text within the newly downloaded file:

```
sed -i 's/srcset="[^"]*"//g' $0
```

To launch HTTrack Cli with this option you can write a command like:

```bash
httrack https://website.to.copy.co.uk/ -V "sed -i \'s/srcset="[^"]*"//g\' \$0"
```

*In summary:*
Each time a file is downloaded by HTTrack, run the `sed` command on the file. If `srcset` is present, remove it.

Answer (score -1):

If you are using WordPress,

install the plugin [Code Snippets](https://wordpress.org/plugins/code-snippets/). Add a new snippet with the following code:

```php
add_filter( 'wp_calculate_image_srcset_meta', '__return_null' );
```

Press the "Save changes and Active" button. This snippet will remove srcset tag from your site. [Code Source](https://ntorga.com/remove-srcset-on-wordpress/)

Comment: That is a WordPress plugin. That is only going to help if you are downloading your own WordPress website.

Comment: I downvoted because your answer is only specific to WordPress. The question here is related to HTTrack management of `srcset` tags.